# Git diff --stat explanation

Tags: git, diff, diffstat

[Git's pull output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340051/what-does-the-output-of-git-pull-actually-mean) has been explained here fairly well. In spite of this I'm still unsure exactly what the text graph relates to.

For example:

`git diff --stat master HEAD^`

Outputs (truncated):

`Site/index.php     |  118 ++--`

While the number of lines modified is clearly displayed as 118, the text graph is a little harder to interpret.

Could this relate to the ratio of added and removed lines?

Comment: 118 ++-- indicates that a total of 118 changes were made. ++-- (2+, 2- , or approximately 50%,50%) shows that roughly 50% of these 118 changes were new lines (50% of 118 is 59 new lines) and roughly 50%  of these 119 changes were lines removed. 
If it was, for example, 118 +++--, it would suggest that circa 60% of the changes were new lines (totaling 60% of 118 changes is 70 new line). 
Or, as last example, 118 ++++-, it would suggest that circa 80% of the 118 changes were new lines (totaling 80% of 118 changes is 94 new lines).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Yes it's the ratio of added and removed lines.

See also:

```
man diffstat
```

Comment: What is the scale? Is 100% the same for all file sizes?

Comment: Site/index.php | 118 ++-- means : roughly 50% removed 50% added on index.php. The ++-- indicator is not very precise.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. I was thrown off by a diffstat which was entirely pluses. I made the assumption that a ratio would have been displayed in its simplistic form.

Comment: Unfortunately, `man diffstat` doesn't work in Git Bash on Windows.

Answer (score 33):

```sh
git diff --numstat "@{1 day ago}"
```

**Parameters:**

- `diff` = Show diff
- `--numstat` = show the number of lines inserted and removed
- `@{1 day ago}` = Period.

---

#### Output

```
0   1   WebContent/WEB-INF/tags/Grid.tag
38  30  ant/build.xml
```

- Column 1 (containing `0` `38`) = inserted
- Column 2 (containing `1` `30`) = removed

PS: Columns are separated by tab (`\t`).

Answer (score 15):

As I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13763549/1031900):

It supposed to reflect the amount of changes (in lines) of each file listed.
Plus signs for additions, minuses for deletions.

The *118* gives the amount of changed lines, and the *-* / *+* gives you the proportion of deletions/additions.
When the amount of changes can fit a line you'll get '*+*' per addition, '*-*' per deletion;
Otherwise, this is an approximation, e.g.

```
CHANGES.txt     |   47 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
make-release.py |   77 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++----------------
2 files changed, 102 insertions(+), 22 deletions(-)
```

On `CHANGES.txt` since you can see that there are no '*-*', and since 47 '*+*' are a lot you have a proportionate amount of them (i.e. 100%).
On `make-release.py` you'll see *x39* '*+*' standing for 55 additions and *x16* '*-*' standing for 22 deletions.
Exactly as their proportion, and just the amount to fit output screen.

The amount of signs per line the a `GCD` multiple that fits the line width.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I know it has been a bit but do you have any idea why one might not show the total when there is room? I have a line that shows `|   3 -` but I also have a line that shows `|  55 +++----` so there is room for three `-`s but it only showed 1

Comment: It looks like if all the changes in the diff can fit at 1:1 scale, they will be printed at 1:1. But if any file's amount of changes is too long for the line, all of them will be scaled proportionately.