# What are these symbols next to "merge mode by recursive" in git merge?

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-pull

When I use `git pull [project name] master` to update my core files, I get a bunch of green plus and red minus signals under "merge made by recursive." What are these symbols and what do they mean?

Here's a screenshot:

[image: git pull]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The answers to later duplicates of this question have fuller answers, e.g. [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3340304/575530) and [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13763549/575530)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That is an approximation of how many lines have changed. Pluses are for new content and minuses are for what was taken out. Modifications end up with equal amount of both. Deletions are only minuses and new files are all pluses.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And you can see the same style of diff output using `git diff --stat [args]`.