# Output of git pull command

Tags: git, git-pull, fast-forward

I used `git pull git@github.com:myaccount/random.git` for updating my local git directory.
I found following result on shell

```
 Fast forward
 .htaccess                         |    2 +-
 folder_name/file1.php                    |   74 ++--------------
 folder_name/file1.php                    |    2 +-
 folder_name/file2.php                    |    2 +-
 folder_name/css/style.css                 |    1 +
 folder_name/file3.html                     |  167 -------------------------------------
 folder_name/file4.php                      |   78 ++---------------
 folder_name/file5.php                   |   32 ++------
 folder_name/file6.php                     |  108 ------------------------
 folder_name/file7.php              |   77 -----------------
 folder_name/file8.php                     |    4 +-
 folder_name/file9.php                      |    5 +-
 folder_name/file10.php                      |   31 ++-----
 folder_name/file11.php                   |   16 ----
 folder_name/file12.php                     |   64 +++++---------
 folder_name/pics/items/file13.png |  Bin 0 -> 91578 bytes
 folder_name/file14.html                     |   44 ----------
 folder_name/file15.php                      |  102 ++++-------------------
 folder_name/file16.php                      |  112 +++----------------------
 19 files changed, 94 insertions(+), 827 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 folder_name/.htaccess
 delete mode 100644 folder_name/file3.html
 delete mode 100644 folder_name/6.php
 delete mode 100644 folder_name/7.php
 delete mode 100644 folder_name/11.php
 create mode 100644 folder_name/pics/items/file13.png
 delete mode 100644 folder_name/file14.html
```

I tried to understand following output and understood upto a limit. I got what is delelte mode or create mode. But what is number after `|` sign and what does `+` and `-` are representing. and what is `Fast Forward` in start of the line. I found more things like if a file is deleted, its output after `|` is consist of only number and `-`s. So what does it actually mean?

Comment: Take a look here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616742/git-merge-what-are-these-symbols-next-to-merge-mode-by-recursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fast forward is the hashed commit pointer moving to the most current commit it can without merging required.  The pluses and minuses are the changes to lines in the files, the insertions/deleted message is the sum of the changes.   The pluses and minuses are just approximations.