# why did "git clone" stop after unpacking object:100%, done

Tags: git, github, clone

```
$ git fetch pb
remote: Counting objects: 9, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 9 (delta 0), reused 3 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (9/9), done.
```

So I can not clone any code from server. Could anyone help me?

Comment: I use proxy to access web, and I have configured http.proxy.

Comment: What error message are you getting? The `Unpacking objects` message would seem to indicate things went correctly.

Answer (score 1):

On an empty repo, the fetch will do nothing else (as mentioned in "[What does the output of git pull actually mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340051/what-does-the-output-of-git-pull-actually-mean)").
It will [update FETCH_HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10697486/6309).

Only a `git pull` would update local branch and the working tree.

But if the command hung after that, as [illustrated by this tweet](http://twitter.com/geeksam/statuses/164764493128278016), it could be a [GitHub status issue](https://status.github.com/).

```
October 15, 2012

04:04 pm PST
GitHub Pages was down from 3:50-3:59 pm. We're investigating the cause.

October 14, 2012 – minor interruption occurred

02:55 am PST
All connectivity issues have been resolved.

02:47 am PST
We are investigating errors with GitHub.com and API
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. Found the answer [here](http://hoonzis.blogspot.ca/2012/10/git-stops-after-unpacking-objects-or.html.). Two options, one is the ugly way and involves Ctrl-c'ing when your pull freezes, then running git fsck and git merge on the dangling commit. But there's a better way, if it works, through a method on [this blog](http://sparethought.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/setting-git-to-work-behind-ntlm-authenticated-proxy-cntlm-to-the-rescue/) which describes how to use CNTLM.

Git doesn't work well with NTLM proxies, which is what you'll have in most corporate environments. The solution is to setup a local proxy that redirects traffic, which is what CNTLM does.

Install [CNTLM](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cntlm/files/), modify the .ini file to inlcude your user id, domain, password, and proxy settings. Start the proxy, then run this in your Git Bash:  git config --global http.proxy localhost:3128

Should now work!

Comment: Interesting alternative case to my answer. +1